# How to download images from mobile application using webdriver\appium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

How to download images from mobile application using webdriver\appium?
for example: whatsapp, amazon

Comment: Could you step back a bit and clarify why you need to use WebDriver / Appium? What are you trying to test?

Comment: ++ what are you trying to test?

Comment: I want to download images from native mobile applications (whatsapp or amazon app), via automation(I selected appium for it.).

Comment: But what for? If you're scraping images from those sites, do it from the sites, not the apps. That would be vastly quicker and easier.

Answer (score 3):

***If*** the sole purpose of your task is to download some images that are coming in through a Native app like Amazon or Whatsapp, you don't need a high level framework like Appium or web driver. You can accomplish that task through  network layer.

To start with, While browsing through the images that you are interested in hook up [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles proxy](http://charlesproxy.com), enable SSL proxying, install root cert etc. to see what are the HTTP requests that are giving the images.

You can mimic the exact same thing using network requests in your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) library.

After you added the library, the code will looks like:

```
File fileToSaveImage = new File(dirToSave, normalizedName);
HtmlImage elementHtmlImage = (HtmlImage) pageWithImage.<HtmlImage>getFirstByXPath(X_PATH_FOR_IMAGE);
elementHtmlImage.saveAs(fileToSaveImage);
```

Of course you have to care about `X_PATH_FOR_IMAGE`, but I am sure it can be generalized by some site-specific pattern.

Comment: Note: this is an answer for `web` application. Not for `native` and I am afraid not for `hybrid`